# How to use wild card % in python string for sql statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm having this situation to check whether an account number exists in a row in database. The column can contain a number of account numbers each separated by a comma eg. 00001,00002,00003. 
eg case:`SELECT * FROM finance_collection.member WHERE account_ids LIKE 00001,% OR %,00001 OR %,00001,% OR 00001`
For this I wrote an SQL statement as:

```
account_exists = " SELECT * FROM finance_collection.member WHERE account_ids LIKE %s,% OR %,%s OR %,%s,% OR %s "
```

Here %s is the incoming account number  , is a comma and % is a multicharacter wildcard.

```
    try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = sqls.account_exists
        cursor.execute(sql, (account, account, account, account))
        return True

    except pymysql.Error as error:
    print(error)
    return False
```

I'm using pymysql to connect and it seems the query isn't working. I tried various combinations like surrounding `%s,%` with `' '` and others but none of them worked. Can you show me a light here?

Comment: "the query isn't working." can you be more specific? error? wrong results? what? remove the try/except to find out the whole traceback.

Comment: have you tried escape '\' the % character?

Comment: Did you try to run this query directly in the DB? ;)

Comment: Double your `%` to escape them.

Comment: @AndrewPaxson that won't work. It'll raise `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: @AbidHasan ah your right

Answer (score 1):

Escape the % with another % (yes this doesn't make much sense but it is what it is):

```
x = "a=%sx%%2C" % ('text')
x
>>> 'a=textx%2C'
```